# Application in Android Market not compatible with device

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I've upload my application to Android Market, but my developer's device is not compatible with it.
Is there a way to know what happens and what is missing?

Comment: my dear, why it is not compatible? Have you tested the build on the same device before uploading this app on market? May your device don't have that particular feature which you have used in app.

Comment: Please elaborate this question with enough detail otherwise people close it as "Not Real question" so you should take care while asking question. All the best

Comment: Application works fine if I installed it from the APK, but in Market application is not compatible

Comment: And I want to know why. For that I'm trying to find a tool which can show me something like trace or log for Market

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another issue (apart from screen density/size) might be permissions.

If you include a permission (e.g. Camera) and your device does not have a camera then the market will tell you, that the app isn't compatible even if the camera is not an essential part of your app. you can avoid this by declaring the feature "not required". See the box on the right of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your screen density? (you can only if your phone is rooted)

New market also checks screen density. Screen density or size may be the issue.

Comment: My screen density is default, device is not rooted